# Считать строку неизвестной длины из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Есть файл, в нём записана строка неизвестной длинны, как мне её записать в массив `char`? Я что-то пытался, но ничего не вышло.

Вот убрал лишнее из кода, насчет двойного указателя не уверен.

```
char **str; //вот сюда надо записать из файла
char ch;
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen("test.txt","r"))==NULL) {
  printf("File not found.\n");
}

do {
  ch = getc(fp);//read 

  //тут видимо должен быть чудо-код

} while(ch!=EOF);

fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Примерно так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    unsigned int N = 10, delta=10, i = 0;   
    char* buf = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*N);    
    while ((buf [i] = fgetc(f)) != EOF  )  {                
        if (++i >= N) {
            N += delta;
            buf = (char*) realloc (buf, sizeof(char)*N);        
        }   
    } 
    fclose(f);
    buf[i] = '\0';
    puts (buf); 
    free (buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только если нужна строка, то в while можно поверить на '\\n' и выйти.

А в линуксе есть библиотечная функция [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) для подобного чтения.

Comment: А вдруг в файле только одна строка и она не заканчивается на `'\n'` ?

Comment: `getline` - это здорово, но не переносимо. А ТС не указал платформу...

И потом, `getline` примерно так и устроена. Пусть учащийся попишет велосипеды, это полезно )))

Comment: Тогда выход будет по EOF (как у Вас и написано). 

Просто добавить внутрь while if (buf[i] == '\\n').

Но getline() весьма удобна.

Comment: Да. Я как-то не зафиксировался на том, что требуется именно одна строка... Вот пусть ТС сам исправит код для упражнения.

Comment: Пусть. А может за часок и getline реализовать. Ничего сложного. 

Вообще у меня давно был (и есть) аналог. Только он еще позволяет несколько строк с \\ в конце, как одну читать.

Тоже раньше getline назывался, пока при переносе в линукс с библиотечной не пересекся.

Comment: спасибо, код работает! только я не понял, почему N нужно на 10 увеличивать, можно ведь просто сделать N++ и вместо if тоже написать i++ или тут без разница как?
платформа windows

Comment: `N` - это актульный размер буфера, `i` - это позиция чтения в буфер. Когда i доходит до конца буфера, буфер и переменная N увеличивается на `delta`. А конкретные цифры я привел от балды, можно любые написать, только не очень маленькие (тогда придется очень часто вызывать `realloc`, а это довольно прожорливая функция) и не очень большие (может много памяти остаться неиспользованной).

Comment: Можно N и delta делать и не очень маленькими (например, 1024), а после выхода из while сделать realloc() до актуального размера.

Comment: Э-э-э, а не лучше ли вместо посимвольного дергания читать блок (скажем, 4 килобайта), и в нем найти '\n' (а при отсутствии повторить). Ну и потом сделать `fseek` в нужную позицию, если надо, конечно.

Я, правда, подозреваю, что glibc под капотом все отбуферизирует (наверное, хотя я не уверен), но все же, это как-то vendor-specific, вроде бы.

Comment: @drdaeman экономите микросекунды? Пересылки-то только в оперативке -- с диска всё равно блоками читается.

Comment: Блоки читаются в ядре, соответственно экономим сисколлы, суть переключения контекста. Если, конечно, повторяюсь, libc не буферизирует в юзерспейсе.

Собственно, микросекунды тоже важны. Жалкий миллион строк (а, например, некоторые логи на-амного пожирнее бывают) и вот уже оно секунду думает вместо считанных миллисекунд.

Answer (score 6):

Если в файле только 1 строка, то:

1. Открыть файл
2. Переместиться на конец файла через `fseek(FILE*, 0, SEEK_END)`
3. Через `ftell` получить позицию, это будет длинна строки
4. **1 раз** сделать `malloc` на размер того, что вернул `ftell`
5. Переместиться на начало файла
6. В цикле `пока не EOF` считать содержимое файла в массив

Comment: Это, пожалуй, получше будет для единственной строки.(+)

Comment: @fogbit, чтобы считать в память целый файл (а Вы делаете именно это), цикл не нужен. 

Достаточно одного read. И в таком случае лучше делать не fopen() (ну, зачем тут лишний уровень буферизации), а open() и fstat().

Т.е.

    char * get_file_contents(char *name, size_t *size) {
      int fd = open(name, O_RDONLY);
      char *buf = NULL; *size = -1;
      if (fd != -1) {
       struct stat st;
       fstat(fd, &st);
       if ((*size = st.st_size) && (buf = (char *)malloc(st.st_size)))
          read(fd, buf, st.st_size);
        close(fd);
      }
      return buf;
    }

Вроде так.

Comment: @avp, это если на posix-системах

Comment: @mikillskegg, конечно. А стоит ли на других учиться программировать?

Все равно ведь, не завтра, так через месяц проблемы с вводом-выводом русских буковок начнутся.

Comment: @avp, однако, в мире много несчастных людей, которые вынуждены писать под виндовс.

Comment: @avp: не забывайте об embedded-платформе, которая является одним из естественных доменов для разработки на C. Десктоп всё же поделен между C++/Qt/GTK/MFC и C#/WinForms/WPF, мобильная платформа -- вотчина Java и Objective C.

Comment: @VladD, вряд ли этот вопрос как-то связан с  embedded-платформами.

Тем более, что скорее всего сейчас там все от GNU.

Comment: @avp, ТС же написал, что у него виндовс. Правда, это может быть MinGW...

Comment: @mikillskegg а счастливые должны писать под Contiki?

@avp боюсь, что далеко не всё от GNU. IAR, Keil, да мало ли кто ещё.

Comment: @alexlz, я счастлив тем, что по работе могу сам выбирать платформу. Я выбрал линукс, а когда приходится иметь дело с виндовсом, бываю очень несчастлив.